# Checking if a file exist error

Tags: c#, .net

So I saw an answer in another question saying that this should work:

```
using System.IO;
if (File.Exists(Path))
{
    Action();
}
```

However, when I do this, I get these errors:

```
'System.IO' is a 'namespace', which is not valid in the given context

The Name 'File' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also may want to take a look at ReSharper, a tool (not free) that helps to write cleaner code and shows that type of exceptions right when you type the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either Add `using System.IO;` at top of your file

**Or**

use it like

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path))
{
  //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to put `using System.IO;` at the top of your file outside the class.

Comment: can i ask why this is not the accepted answer ? robbie answered before @Shyju but yet you accepted his answer ?

Comment: maybe its because @Shyju provided the extra alternative of not having a `using`? I'm not really bothered, but thanks for having my corner :)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you're doing exactly, but it looks like you might need some help with the order of your statements.  `using` statements appear at the beginning of the .cs file, and your logic will need to appear in a method within a class.

Here's how it can be done using a console application:

```
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\file.txt";

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Action();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very top of your file:

```
using System.IO; <--

namespace Application1
{
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be outside of namespace declarations, but it must be outside the class declaration